# What is the difference between global and GLOBAL in node

Tags: node.js, global

I'm looking to use node.js to do some testing of existing, browser-based code. Some of the code I'm looking to test looks into the global scope for other functions. (For various reasons, I cannot change this code.)

It appears that I can assign to `global.foo` to make `foo` globally available. This would let me load up the appropriate libraries into the appropriate places. It seems there are two varieties of global object in node: `global`, and `GLOBAL`.

**What is the difference between `global` and `GLOBAL`?**

(Of course, one cannot Google this. The official node documentation does not seem to mention `GLOBAL`, but it exists in the runtime, and is mentioned around the web.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They appear to just be aliases of each other:

```
console.log(global === GLOBAL); // true
```

Comment: Fair enough. I thought there might be some sort of magic, but I guess not.